# Setting toDate function as arrival time Anylogic

Tags: date, anylogic

I'm already struggling for days to use dates from excel in a proper way in anylogic..
I've created a database in where the date is formulated as integers in different columns since otherwise excel is messing up the dates (for example year=2021 , month=12 day=5 hour=6 minute=44 second=0 stands for 2021/12/5 6:44:00)

Now I know this can be converted to a date by the function `toDate(year, month, day, hour, minutes seconds)`. But how can I use this integers to create agent with specific parameters from the database in a source and add to a custom population?

The most simple way is to add a column where the function toDate(......) is added in the database but I do not know how to do this (see picture if it is unclear). Or are there other solutions?

[image: Possible solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: use Dynamic Events.

Create one and in the action code, write `mySource.inject(1)`

In Main, on startup, load all dbase rows and create a DE for each row, below assuming it is only with an hour-column:
[image]
(Use the database query wizard to adjust your query).

In your source object, set it to "call of inject() function"

This will work, but it is quite cumbersome, as you can see. Much easier if you get your Excel right and just import the date column clean and well so you can use the Source option "arrival table in database" directly. I know you need regular arrivals, so maybe code that up in Excel to give you these on specific dates...

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I indeed now did it in Excel. For all the people with the same problem, when importing formulas used in excel, it will mess up the anylogic database, so first work out the excel formulas than copy that specific column, paste it in notepad, copy it from notepad back into the excel sheet so that it is no formulas anymore and after that import it as a database.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Always treat your excel sheets as clean databases before loading: no formula, clean headers (lower case, no spaces), clean data fields, etc. Or best: Avoid Excel :D